# How can I change speed of flashing directly with seekbar in Android App?

Tags: java, android

I making flashlight android app and I made seekbar to change the speed of flashing. but the change in speed not reflected until I press the button in the middle to turn on and off the flash, how can I[github link attached below](https://github.com/hossamsalama/Stroboscopic.git) change speed directly from seekbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. StroboRunner using it's own freq, not a global freq. So, you need to restart thread.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
       freq = progress;
       turnOnOff(powerButton.isChecked());
   }
   ```
2. And, in your source, there is multiple thread that was not terminated.
   Check "this" comment.

private void turnOnOff(boolean on) {

```
    if (on) {
        if (freq != 0) {
            sr = new StroboRunner();
            sr.freq = freq;

            if (t != null) {
                t.interrupt(); // this. kill previous thread.
            }

            t = new Thread(sr);
            t.start();
            return;
        } else
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    }

    if (!on) {
        if (t != null) {
            sr.stopRunning = true;
            t.interrupt(); // this
            t = null;
            return;
        } else
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    }

    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Comment: okay, this changing speed correctly with the seekbar but the power button lost its functionality. when pressing the power button while flashing the light is on and the button is off also when moving seekbar to level 0 and press power button the light is still on until I press the power button again

Comment: @hsalama, well, how about make a new question? Or, you can implement turn light off when progress is zero.